# Get average after groupby for a fair balancing

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

I would like to test if the count (after grouping by technician, numberOfTasksByTechnician) above average for a good balance of tasks for technicians (every technician must do the same number of tasks), how can I get the average (hard coded value 4)

```
Constraint technicianCharge(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory)  {
        return constraintFactory.from(Task.class)
            .groupBy(
                    Task::getTechnician, ConstraintCollectors.countDistinct()
            )
            .filter((technician, count)-> {
                return count > 4; // return count > (?average)
            })
            .penalize("technicianCharge", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, to collect average, you need to write a custom constraint collector. It's not hard to do, check out [count() implementation](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/main/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/stream/ConstraintCollectors.java#L84) for inspiration. When you have your constraint collector, your constraint stream would then look like this:

```
Constraint technicianCharge(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory)  {
    return constraintFactory.from(Task.class)
        .groupBy(
             Task::getTechnician, 
             ConstraintCollectors.countDistinct(),
             MyConstraintCollectors.average(task -> ...)
        )
        .filter((technician, count, average)-> {
            return count > average;
        })
        .penalize("technicianCharge", 
            HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,
            (technician, count, average) -> count - average);
}
```

In the future, we may provide the average constraint collector [out-of-the-box](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2493).

As a footnote, since you mentioned fairness, you may want to see our blog on [OptaPlanner load balancing and fairness](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/02/03/FormulaForMeasuringUnfairness.html).

Answer (score 1):

As of OptaPlanner 8.11.0.Final, 'average' is available out of the box.

https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2021/08/19/ConstraintStreamsSomeMoreLove.html

https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.11.0.Final/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/stream/ConstraintCollectors.html

cheers :D

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30571932)